# Using screen in startup script

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, torrent

I'm trying to write a startup script to launch rtorrent. I've planed on using screen in the script. I tried this command in the startup script :

```
su -l nico -c "screen -dmS rtd rtorrent"
```

But it seems like it doesn't work (i can't get the screen session back) :

```
screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-nico.
```

Do i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

The list of active `screen` sessions is by default maintained independently per user.
In your `screen` launch command, the session was started by user `nico`, so if you want to inquiry about it you should probably run `su -l nico -c 'screen -ls'` instead.